# php development under iis. is it good choice?

Tags: php, iis

I am classic asp developer,  now shifting to PHP, MySQL development. I am using **windows OS**  for my development. I don't want shift on Linux ( this is personal choice , I don't want to get in debate of windows vs Linux ) .

I tried to install php and other stuff on IIS , I am slowly turning towards frameworks like Laravel.

So, is it  good to use php under IIS than apache , what difference will it make if I dont use apache ..

**EDIT**

i just want know, will some feature will disabled under iis, and what will be difference for execution of php script under iis ,

Comment: I would say support, mostly support. PHP on Apache is a very common configuration. In fact, most tutorials you will find online will refer to such a config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use IIS with PHP.  Apache is much easier to set up and much closer to any shared hosting environment you are likely to run your code on.  I used to use IIS for my dev and it always drove me crazy.

I installed Apache on windows and I've never looked back.